Node + Neo4j driver - is there some way to set up a "global" type convertor so any datetime property is ISO8601 string instead of JS object?
Note: NOT a duplicate of Datetime and iso format as it is not related to my question at all. Please do not close my question, as I am asking a different question about global typeconverter, not how to return a datetime as a string. Thank you for your understanding.
I'm using node and neo4j.
Dates, like createdAt or sentAt are stored as datetime($now) where now is new Date().toISOString()
However, when I query records from neo4j, the driver returns a JS object for any datetime types.
Now I can of course do new Date(record.createdAt).toISOString() but that is cumbersome. Or I can explicitly ask the query to return datetime as string. However, that is tedious and I'm just querying whole records since they're stored against a strong type enforcement.
Is there a way to set up a global typeconverter so that if a RECORD has ANY datetime PROPERTY (sentAt, createdAt, whatever), it is automatically converted and returned as ISO8601 string instead of the JS object by default?
For example, is there something like this? (NOT ACTUAL CODE - this obviously won't work, but something like this which can be defined ONCE)
const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password), {
  converters: {
    datetime: convertDatetimeToISOString // will use neo4j.isDateTime to check and return .toString()
  }
});

Right now I'm running my returned record thought a custom function that does that same thing, but it means every time I query I have to first run records through this method before using them. Again, that's fine but I want to know if there's a way to set this up ONCE.
My API consumers expect ISO 8601 strings and I'd like to avoid manual conversion each time.
Thank you

No, I don't think that is possible, but aren't those Neo4j's "DateTime" objects? If so, I believe it has a .toString() method that does what you want.
To test this, try
console.log(result.createdAt)

If this logs as an object, try doing
console.log(`${result.createdAt}`)

If it's what I expect, you should get an ISO 8601 string. The default template literal function calls .toString() on objects passed as arguments. It's the same as
console.log(result.createdAt.toString())

If that works, I'd take a look at your API technology. If you return an object like that, many frameworks automatically call toString() on it. If it doesn't, that'd probably be the "more correct" place to fix this. I generally recommend you keep the lossless objects when you're inside your code and only convert to strings for transport.
Driver source code for DateTime.toString()
Caveat: "correct" is subjective.

Got it. So I just create sessions (or tx from the session) and exec. I have a intermediate function that I run right now which does this, but it means I have to run it every time I get results from exec where the object is checked for any property that isDateTime and converts it to ISO string. I guess I'll just stick to what I'm doing.
